# High System CPU on Sierra

Tags: macos, system-profiler

I am seeing high system CPU on a Macbook Air and performance is hit but the list of processes does not show any obvious culprits.[image: system image]

[image: activity monitor - my processes]

Can I get more details what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common situation. By default, activity monitor shows your main processes “My Processes” only, and in this case the system is busy doing work as a result of your apps or system tasks.

In the view menu, select all processes to see what’s taking all the CPU time.